# .htaccess redirect 301 but dont redirect certain folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains hosted on 2 different servers. Now im redirecting the old domain (on a separate server) with a 301 to the new server.

But now i want to still access a folder on the old server. So if a user types in www.olddomain.com/show/ i want to show the files of the old server dont 301 redirect, end else always redirect.

But how can I do this, everything i tried still redirects to the new server?

im using `Redirect 301 / heremyurl`

A could also make a php file and do the logic in there but This must be possible in .htaccess right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Redirect` directive use `mod_rewrite` rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^show/ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```